# Objective C - Sort an array of string

Tags: objective-c, arrays, string, sorting

I have to sort an array of objects by a property of the objects that is a string.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

you need to use

```
-[NSArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:]
```

or

`-[NSMutableArray sortUsingSelector:]` and pass `@selector(compare:)` as the parameter.

here's a link to the answer
[Sort NSArray of date strings or objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132806/sort-nsarray-of-date-strings-or-objects)

Answer (score 17):

For just sorting array of strings:

```
sorted = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

For sorting objects with key "name":

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)];
sorted = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];
```

Also, instead of `compare:` you can use:

- `caseInsensitiveCompare:`
- `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:`

Answer (score 8):

Here's what I ended up using - works like a charm:

```
[categoryArray sortedArrayWithOptions:0
               usingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
{
    id<SelectableCategory> cat1 = obj1;
    id<SelectableCategory> cat2 = obj2;
    return [cat1.name compare:cat2.name options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
}];
```

`SelectableCategory` is just a `@protocol SelectableCategory <NSObject>` defining the category with all its properties and elements.