# how to sort an array of date objects in it?

Tags: iphone, ios, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort NSArray of date strings or objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132806/sort-nsarray-of-date-strings-or-objects)

I want to sort an array which contain Dates in ascending order

Comment: read this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820979/objective-c-sort-an-array-of-string and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132806/sort-nsarray-of-date-strings-or-objects

Comment: I don't understand why people answer to these kind of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is a very generic way to sort any `NSArray` with any type of objects, using blocks. now, it just is specified as solution for your current problem with the `NSDate` objects.

```
NSArray *_arrayOfDates = // your array with the NSDate objects;
NSArray *_sortedArrayOfDates = [_arrayOfDates sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [((NSDate *) obj1) compare:((NSDate *)obj2)];
}];
NSLog(@"%@", _sortedArrayOfDates);
```

---

*please note:* you can use `NSMutableArray` with `-sortUsingComparator:` method, which provides the same result, but the array will be sorted inside of itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
          NSLog(@"livevideoparsingarray..%@",livevideoparsingarray);
            NSSortDescriptor * descLastname = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"active" ascending:YES];
            [livevideoparsingarray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descLastname, nil]];
            [descLastname release];
            videoparsing = [livevideoparsingarray copy];
```

livevideoparsingarray is my array which I have sort & active is my tag which is in array which I have sort. You change with your requirements.