# how can i sort an NSMutableArray in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort NSArray of date strings or objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132806/sort-nsarray-of-date-strings-or-objects)

Hello,
I want to sort an NSMutableArray.
The MutableArray contain NSstrings.Strings have this form "20112505" YYYY-MM-DD . How can i sort it ? thank you

Comment: Your example date doesn't match your format string. If the format string is correct, you can just sort lexicographically using the `sort` methods on NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[yourMutableArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```