# How to sort an array of dates in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have an array of dates  that  are adding one by one to the table view ,  but i want to sort them in ascending order irrespective of the sequence added them,can any one help me

Comment: here is your answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1134126/919545 and please do some search from next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray* sortedDateList = [dateList sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSDate* dateOne, NSDate* dateTwo) {
    return [dateOne compare:dateTwo];
}];
```

Comment: `return [dateOne compare:dateTwo]` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSMutableArray`'s method `sortUsingComparator`, and write your comparison block using `NSDate`'s `compare` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NSDate object this should be easy:

```
NSDate *date1 = ...;
NSDate *date2 = ...;
NSDate *date3 = ...;

NSArray *dates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:date1,date2,date3,nil];

NSArray *sortedArray = [dates [anArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"beginDate" ascending:TRUE];
[myMutableArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
[sortDescriptor release];
```

Use this sort descriptor for sorting array of dates