# Order NSArray of custom objects based in an attribute of type NSDate

Tags: cocoa, sorting, nsarray

I have a `NSArray` of `AEMEvent` custom objects. One of the properties of this `AEMEvent` class is `startDate` of type `NSDate`.

```
@interface AEMEvent : NSObject
{
    //.....
    NSDate *startDate;
    //..........
}
```

I would like to sort this array based on this property, so the output will be an `NSArray` full of `AEMEvent` objects ordered by `startDate` attribute.

I have seen this interesting answer for sorting an `NSArray` of `NSDate` objects using  `-[NSArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:` or `-[NSMutableArray sortUsingSelector:]` and passing `@selector(compare:)`as parameter and wonder if there will be a way to use this in my situation - [Sort NSArray of date strings or objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132806/sort-nsarray-of-date-strings-or-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Sort AMEvent by startDate 

NSSortDescriptor * firstDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] 
                                       initWithKey:@"startDate" ascending:YES 
                                       selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]

NSArray * descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstDescriptor, nil];  
NSArray * sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```