# Sorting NSArray of objects on Date property

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I'm trying to sort an `NSArray` of objects based on a date property. The order I'm looking for is the most recent date first, ending with the earliest date.

e.g 
05/15/2014
05/12/2014
02/20/2014
25/12/2013
10/11/2013

I've attempted a number of different approaches seen in the accepted answer in "[**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it)" thread.

But my ordering is off for example

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dateToPay" ascending:YES];
            NSArray *orderedArray = [cashFlowItemsArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
            self.cashFlowItems = orderedArray;
```

is returning:
02/20/2014
05/12/2014
05/15/2014
10/11/2013
12/25/2013

So the year is ordered correctly, the months and days are wrong

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I assume your Date object is a string, and not an `NSDate`?

Comment: 02/20/2014 &  25/12/2013 whats the date format here ? "dd/MM/yyyy" or "MM/dd/yyyy" . i thing you are formatting these with two different formatter, before adding them to cashFlowItemsArray.

Comment: create NSDate objects and sort by those.

Comment: @pawan 
thats a typo teh format is mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: I just edited to correct those errors

Comment: @stonz2 The date is an NSDate not a string

Comment: They are sorted in string order. Show some more of how the array and and date items are created.

Comment: I'm parsing json data into a cashflowobject. The array is filled with these objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this , i have tested your code

```
 NSArray *stringDateArray = @[@"05/15/2014",@"05/12/2014",@"02/20/2014",@"05/12/2013",@"10/11/2013"];

 NSMutableArray *dateArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[stringDateArray count]];

for (NSString *dateString in stringDateArray) {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

    [dateArray addObject:@{@"date":[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]}];
}

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
NSArray *orderedArray = [dateArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

NSLog(@"ordered array--%@",orderedArray);
```

---

> ordered array--(
>           {
>           date = "2013-05-11 18:30:00 +0000";
>       },
>           {
>           date = "2013-10-10 18:30:00 +0000";
>       },
>           {
>           date = "2014-02-19 18:30:00 +0000";
>       },
>           {
>           date = "2014-05-11 18:30:00 +0000";
>       },
>           {
>           date = "2014-05-14 18:30:00 +0000";
>       }
>   )

### with compare selector

```
NSArray *stringDateArray = @[@"05/15/2014",@"05/12/2014",@"02/20/2014",@"05/12/2013",@"10/11/2013"];

NSMutableArray *dateArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[stringDateArray count]];

for (NSString *dateString in stringDateArray) {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

    [dateArray addObject:[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]];
}

NSArray *orderedArray = [dateArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

NSLog(@"ordered array--%@",orderedArray);
```

---

> ordered array--(
>       "2013-05-11 18:30:00 +0000",
>       "2013-10-10 18:30:00 +0000",
>       "2014-02-19 18:30:00 +0000",
>       "2014-05-11 18:30:00 +0000",
>       "2014-05-14 18:30:00 +0000"
>   )

Comment: My array is an array of objects, each object has a date property. I'm trying to order of that property

Comment: please correct me here , you have a array with date property ? means inside of your array , you have a dictionary with key @"date" & object @"NSDate" rihgt?

Comment: I have an array, the array is filled with objects of the same type, each object has a date property, the data type of the date property is an NSdate

Comment: will you show me the code how you fill your cashFlowItemsArray ?

Comment: The data is being returned from an API call, within the reponse i'm parsing Json data into a cashflowitem object, I've then poulated the array with these cashflowitem objects.

Comment: can you post the json response here?

Comment: jsonItems:
{
    amount = 50;
    checkEnteredManually = 0;
    checkNumber = *********;
    dateEntered = "10/22/2013";
    dateToPay = "10/23/2013";
    description = "Visa Platinum";
    func = billPayGetOutstanding;
    matches = "*****************";
    paymentAmount = 50;
    paymentID = 618;
    pmtkey = "******************";
    recurrence = 0;
    status = Outstanding;
    vendorID = 23;
    vendorName = ********;
}

i've covered any sensitive data with *, but that basically the response

Comment: dateToPay contain string object , right ? i can see that when you are sorting it , you get object sorted by sring. you need to convert them into nsdate as i have done with a datefomatter , after that you can sort it.

Comment: So in my cashflowitem i've created a setter for the date, it changes the string to date upon creation! and my @(selector)compare is now doing the job. Thanks Dude!

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate: [Sort NSArray of date strings or objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132806/sort-nsarray-of-date-strings-or-objects)

He basically states (assuming your array is filled with NSDate objects) to use the compare: selector for dates. So do this:

```
NSArray *orderedArray = [dateArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

He states:

> This is simpler than creating an NSSortDescriptor, and much simpler
>   than writing your own comparison function. (NSDate objects know how to
>   compare themselves to each other at least as efficiently as we could
>   hope to accomplish with custom code.)

Comment: I get the exact same results using the @selector(compare:)

Comment: Did you copy my code because I got it wrong (I fixed it now).

Answer (score 0):

Make your array into a NSDate array with this code in a for:

`NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString: @"02/20/2014"];`

Then:

`[dateArray sortUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];`