# How to sort date @"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a" with respect to date and time in decreasing order

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nscalendar

how to sort this Array contains date and time, i need to sort for same dates  ,if i have same dates multiple entries i need to sort it in decreasing order based on the time  and it will be shown in dressing order all the entries.

```
    data= {
     {
            dateAndTime = "04/03/2017 09:52 PM";
            deviceImage = "";
            dialOrReceive = 0;
            number = "+918839752179";
            profilePhoto = "";
        },
            {
            dateAndTime = "02/03/2017 06:54 PM";
            deviceImage = "";
            deviceImage = "";
            dialOrReceive = 0;
            number = "+918839752179";
            profilePhoto = "";
        },
            {
            dateAndTime = "04/03/2017 05:36 PM";
            deviceImage = "";
            dialOrReceive = 0;
            number = "+918839752179";
            profilePhoto = "";
        },
            {
            dateAndTime = "03/03/2017 04:48 PM";
            deviceImage = "";
            dialOrReceive = 0;
            number = "+918839752179";
            profilePhoto = "";
        }, {
            dateAndTime = "03/03/2017 06:48 PM";
            deviceImage = "";
            dialOrReceive = 0;
            number = "+918839752179";
            profilePhoto = "";
        },{
            dateAndTime = "02/03/2017 09:36 PM";
            deviceImage = "";
            dialOrReceive = 0;
            number = "+918839752179";
            profilePhoto = "";
        },
}
```

Comment: Any attempts, what did you try? please post code snippets

Comment: The object for key `data` seems to be an array, not a dictionary. You need to map the date strings to `NSDate` to be able to sort the array.

Comment: i am sorting the the dates successfully  :                                 NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"dateAndTime" ascending: NO];
     arr=[arr sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]];

Comment: for time i am getting issues :(

Comment: @kumar what means "dressing order"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort NSArray of date strings or objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132806/sort-nsarray-of-date-strings-or-objects)

Comment: I need sorted order: LIKE.                          

04/03/2017 09:52 PM
04/03/2017 05:36 PM
03/03/2017 06:48 PM
03/03/2017 04:48 PM
02/03/2017 09:36 PM
02/03/2017 06:54 PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
- (void)sortDict {

    NSDictionary *dict = @{
                           @"data" : @[@{
                                           @"dateAndTime" : @"04/03/2017 09:52 PM",
                                           @"deviceImage" : @"",
                                           @"dialOrReceive" : @0,
                                           @"number" : @"+918839752179",
                                           @"profilePhoto" : @""
                                           },
                                       @{
                                           @"dateAndTime" : @"02/03/2017 06:54 PM",
                                           @"deviceImage" : @"",
                                           @"dialOrReceive" : @0,
                                           @"number" : @"+918839752179",
                                           @"profilePhoto" : @""
                                           },
                                       @{
                                           @"dateAndTime" : @"04/03/2017 05:36 PM",
                                           @"deviceImage" : @"",
                                           @"dialOrReceive" : @0,
                                           @"number" : @"+918839752179",
                                           @"profilePhoto" : @""
                                           },
                                       @{
                                           @"dateAndTime" : @"03/03/2017 04:48 PM",
                                           @"deviceImage" : @"",
                                           @"dialOrReceive" : @0,
                                           @"number" : @"+918839752179",
                                           @"profilePhoto" : @""
                                           },
                                       @{
                                           @"dateAndTime" : @"03/03/2017 06:48 PM",
                                           @"deviceImage" : @"",
                                           @"dialOrReceive" : @0,
                                           @"number" : @"+918839752179",
                                           @"profilePhoto" : @""
                                           },
                                       @{
                                           @"dateAndTime" : @"02/03/2017 09:36 PM",
                                           @"deviceImage" : @"",
                                           @"dialOrReceive" : @0,
                                           @"number" : @"+918839752179",
                                           @"profilePhoto" : @""
                                           },
                                       @{
                                           @"dateAndTime" : @"02/03/2017 07:36 AM",
                                           @"deviceImage" : @"",
                                           @"dialOrReceive" : @0,
                                           @"number" : @"+918839752179",
                                           @"profilePhoto" : @""
                                           }
                                       ]
                            };

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a";

    NSArray *arr = [dict objectForKey:@"data"];

    arr = [arr sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {

        NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:[obj1 objectForKey:@"dateAndTime"]];
        NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:[obj2 objectForKey:@"dateAndTime"]];

        return [date2 compare:date1];
    }];

    NSLog(@"%@", arr);
}
```

Comment: Thank You @schmidt9

Comment: I am sorting but its nor coming in proper way time not sorting properly @schmidt9

Comment: @kumar once again what sorting order do you need for dates and what for time?

Comment: I need sorted order: LIKE.                          

04/03/2017 09:52 PM
04/03/2017 05:36 PM
03/03/2017 06:48 PM
03/03/2017 04:48 PM
02/03/2017 09:36 PM
02/03/2017 06:54 PM

Comment: @kumar ok I edited my answer, it outputs exactly in this order, I added one more record to check for AM case